# Implementing an ActionBar to a custom MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface, menu, android-actionbar

I am trying to implement an ActionBar into my existing project but don't know where to start. I immediately started building a classic menu button menu, before I realized that it is deprecated and some devices (nexus 7) can't access such menus.

What is a good way of implementing an ActionBar over a map? I am already deep into this project and it is due in a  couple of days so rewriting the program is not really an option.

What I am really looking for is two or three simple options always available at the top or bottom of the map which extend to a list if clicked. Thanks !

Comment: MapView is now depecrated. Please use Maps API V2.

Comment: Your kidding ! Would it be possible to simply download and replace the old sdk or is the API completely different? I have a nearly complete project for college due in a couple of days, I would really like to use v2 but I don't know how much time I would have to port everything over...

Comment: My post was a little scary I know, please read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

Comment: You can of course still use V1, but V2 will give you really less code, no more GeoPoints, working directly with Latitude, Longitude, etc... Look at the answer below, that's the correct one, just download the Maps Plugin from ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing ActionBar in a back-compatible way you would probably want to use [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) and its [Maps plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps). 
Take a look at its samples, it's pretty simple to use.